# CoreData & Codable: Avoiding duplicate

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, codable

I have NSManagedObject subclass (CarBrand) with just two properties:

```
public class CarBrand: NSManagedObject, CDCodable {
    @NSManaged public var id: Int64
    @NSManaged public var name: String
}
```

Also I'm using Codable protocol to parse it from server response's JSON. In case if response matches (or nearly matches) my model - there isn't problems with duplication of object (I have static method on that class, that returns object from CoreData or Creates new and returns it).

But one of the responses has following structure:

```
class CarBrandsResponse: Codable {
    let offset: Int
    let count: Int
    let results: [CarBrand]
}
```

In this case I cannot find solution to call that static method for each CarBrand, because if I write

```
self.results = try container.decode([CarBrand].self, forKey: .results)
```

It calls init(from:) in CarBrand for each entry, that means duplication of entity...

I've tried to repeat Decodable behavior, but there I've not found suitable API-method for that. (`unkeyedContainer(), nestedContainer(), etc.`)

Hope you will help me to solve this problem or suggest another way to avoid duplicating.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh I've already found solution, thanks to Apple Swift open source :)

Comment: In that case post an answer for others to see if they stumble upon the same problem

Comment: Could you please share the solution. I was struggling with the same issue